# Best way of keeping my data when changing hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot, disk-cloning

I'm about to get a SSD and I'd like to know what is the way of keeping the data from my mechanical hard drive. I have OpenSUSE and Windows 7 installed on a dual boot. I've found on Google two ways which are cloning the hard drive and collecting the name of all the packages installed of Linux, then reinstall them and reconfigure everything !

- I'm using a laptop, and I'm not sure I have enough ports to connect both drives. What is the solution if I don't?
- With a cloning, will both systems been kept (with the partitions and all this stuff)?
- Is there a better and simpler solution? I have a huge external drive if it can help...

Comment: Does the external drive have any data on it, or is it blank?

Comment: Do you have spare USB ports?  Get a USB SATA external dock.

Comment: @cpast It has data on it, but I can move it somewhere else if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Zoredache. Now I have the solution in case I don't have enough ports.

Comment: What are the relative sizes of the old and new drives?

Comment: The new one has 500GB and the old one has 320 GB